# Single form submission of data from multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, dom-events

I have the following (simplified) HTML code containing two forms:

```
<html>
  <form name="form1" method="get">
    Name: <select name="name" type="text">
      <option selected>A</option>
      <option>B</option>          
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <form name="form2" method="post" action="../cgi/test.pl">
    City: <input name="city" type="text"/>
    Country: <input name="country" type="text"/>
    <input value="Click Me!" type="submit"/>
  </form>
</html>
```

Thus when clicking the submission button the CGI script is executed and I would like the script to be able to ingest also the name selected in the dropdown of the first form. Any suggestion on how to achieve this? In older questions I just found similar things but not suitable for my problem (if I am not wrong...).

Comment: you'll need javascript for that

Comment: @sauhardnc Yes, this is what I understood by looking at older questions. But none of the approaches I found and tried to modify worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a snippet which works as you want, I've done the explaining in the comments wherever necessary. See if this works for you.

```html
<form name="form1" method="get">
  Name:
  <select name="name" type="text" onchange="document.querySelector('#any_id').value = this.value" style="width: 50%">
    <!-- trigger onchange event and change the value of hidden field in the second form -->
    <option selected>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</form>
<hr>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="../cgi/test.pl">
  <!--<input type="hidden" name="any_name" id="any_id" value="Your-default-value"> -->
  <!-- Make this field hidden↓↓, here only for demo purpose-->
  Hidden Field: <input type="text" name="any_name" id="any_id" value="A"><br><br>
  <!-- Give it a default value from your select element(which is A) -->
  City: <input name="city" type="text" /><br><br> Country: <input name="country" type="text" /><br><br>
  <input value="Click Me!" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then get the value from the `name` of hidden field(here `any_name`).

Comment: happy to help. :)